# 301 Redirect Module

Tags: redirection

I need to redirect specific broken/dead links to other pages within my site. I'm looking for a module that I can setup, then have my support team change without needed htaccess, etc.

I came across the [Path Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module, which then sent me to the [Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module. Can the Redirect module accomplish that? Again, I am NOT looking to redirect the entire site nor looking to setup redirect rules. I need to redirect specific pages, and would like a non-dev on my team to be able to do so.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the Redirect module will do this.  It will go through the `{watchdog}` table for "Page Not Found" errors, and then give you a UI for adding redirects for each 404 it found.  My team (many of which are non-technical) have been able to manage this without me writing any manual redirects.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for verifying this. I got my team in there and they love it. It would be nice if there was a simple CSV upload option, since I have a bunch of URLs to redirect, but I'll take this.

Comment: How/where is the UI? Can't find it

Comment: @GuillaumeBois It's admin/config/search/redirect

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for Global redirect module: https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect

[Global redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect): Global Redirect searches for an alias of the current URL and does a 301 redirects to it if found. This prevents content from being displayed on multiple urls when the path module is enabled. Displaying duplicate content at multiple url's can cause a loss of search engine site ranking. This way it is very useful to maintain the site ranking along with maintaining the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt on global redirect module as the description provided pretty much says global redirect module role is to kill the redundant route for a page, so if you have a node with path alias www.yoursite.com/xxxx there will be parallel route for the same page as
www.yoursite.com/node/nid so this will make row ranking in seo,

if your question is to redirect specific broken/dead links to other pages within my site
 [redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module is the one you are looking for.